# Synchronized digital cameras

Tags: embedded, camera, synchronous

at the moment im doing some research. 
I want to create an embedded "application" with two digital cameras ( > 30fps, global shutter, >= 800x600 resolution ) on an Freescale Arm iMx. 6 Quad (i think its a good choice for later image processing).

At the moment for me it is not clear, how to synchronise these two cameras. Do i need a Framegrabber ? - which Cameras ( Ethernet , ... )

greetings

Comment: This is an area where FPGAs excel.

Comment: Matt Young, thanks for the fast comment. can you give me more details ? is there something available on the market ?

Comment: There are truck loads of FPGAs on the market, and you design a state machine to pull data from the cameras. Once it works, copy it, and have the two run side by side. The cameras will be in sync.

Comment: How synchronized you need the two images to be (within 1s? within 1 ns?) and how much time/money you are willing to spend?

Comment: @bigjosh, <1ms would be really great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Raspberry Pi Camera Module...

[image]

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1367

This is a pretty mediocre module, but might be good for your project because...

1. It is capable of capturing a single whole frame and you can trigger that from asn external system via a pin (FREX), so you could trigger a pair of these sensors with a single signal.
2. You can manually control all of the image parameters, so you set a pair of modules to capture matched images.
3. It is cheap, readily available, and comes on a handy breakout board.
4. It is [documented](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Dev/RaspberryPi/ov5647_full.pdf).
5. You can plug it into a Raspberry Pi and have a working system to start with and then make modifications to get the functionality you want, rather than starting from scratch.

Below are some suggestions on how to start. They are in order of increasing tightness of sync, and increasing effort so I would test at each step and stop as soon as you get enough sync for your application.

1. Get 2 Raspberry Pis and get them working with 2 normal, independent Camera Modules.
2. Modify code so you can manually adjust image parameters, and set both sensors to use the same parameters.
3. Modify code so you can enable frame exposure mode. More info in section 4.10 of the data sheet.

[image]

3. Get physical access to the FREX pin on each module.

[image]

I don't have a module here, but this could either be as easy as tapping a test point, or as hard as desoldering the module form to board to add a line.

Connect both FREX pins together and use them to trigger a synchronized capture.

4. Get Physical access to the XCLK clock input on both modules and get both modules to run form a single source.
5. Write up everything you did because I think a lot of people would love to be able to do this!

Comment: The new Arducam (which is directly compatible to the rpi libraries and raspistill and other rpi tools, as well as connector etc, its 'plug in and go') now has FREX and STROBE pins : see it here : http://www.arducam.com/raspberry-pi-camera-rev-c-improves-optical-performance/ This helps hugely, but it does not solve the coding issue of modifying the RPI libraries to setup FREX mode. I am currently attempting this and its not so easy.